# Pandas reading excel file with some dates missing

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, reshape, timedelta

I have an excel file:

```
Date        Time    Value
1-May-04    00:00   3.74618
1-May-04    00:15   3.58507
1-May-04    00:30   3.30998
```

I need to convert it to:

```
                    Value
Date
2004-05-01 0:00     3.74618
2004-05-01 0:15     3.58507
2004-05-01 0:30     3.30998
```

Normally I pass to `pd.read_excel()`

```
parse_dates = {'Date': ['Date','Time']}
```

and it works great, but in some files some Date entries are missing which confuses pandas Index. So I have to read the file without parsing dates/times, then remove the lines with empty Date:

```
frame = frame.loc[pd.notnull(frame.index)]
```

And then combine Date+Time manually, which is not very nice. Is it possible to drop lines without Date during read?

Comment: Try `error_bad_lines=False` as additional argument to `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: It doesn't error as such - instead of creating Timestamp index (by adding date and time columns) - instead it creates multi index, I guess because it's confused by missing dates. I just want to drop the records with dates empty